# Smooth transition from SVG Triangle clip to Circle

Tags: html, css, svg, hover, transition

I am using SVG to clip-path an image to a triangle. My goal is to have the path expand and become a circle on hover (in a smooth transition).

The closest I've found is this codepen as a response to a site-challenge:
http://codepen.io/enjikaka/pen/hCGjE
And it certainly transitions, but it seems to be very different from the clipping that I'm doing. I'm very novice about svg (only just started using it to create these triangles).

Here is my code (an up triangle clip and down triangle clip both in bootstrap col-sm-4 divs):

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class='tri-up'>
                            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 87">
                              <clipPath id="clipTriangleUp">
                                <polygon points="0 87,100 87,50 0"/>
                              </clipPath>
                              <image clip-path="url(#clipTriangleUp)" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="http://placehold.it/560x484"/>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                           <div class='tri-down'>
                            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 87">
                              <clipPath id="clipTriangleDown">
                                <polygon points="0 0,100 0,50 87"/>
                              </clipPath>
                              <image clip-path="url(#clipTriangleDown)" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="http://placehold.it/560x484"/>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

There are a few other classes I have in here, and it makes 6 triangles, (up and down) in two rows of three. Negative margins push the triangles closer together than the bootstrap columns.

If anyone has any idea how to accomplish this, I have scoured the internet to no avail and your help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: A lot depends on what you expect the transition from triangle to circle (and vice versa) to look like.  I can think of several ways.  Perhaps you could add more information?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau thanks for responding! My thought at this juncture is just that beggars can't be choosers. I'm just looking for a smooth transition from a triangle clip to a circle one on hover.

Comment: I added many edits to the question though so you can see some context

Comment: If you use a path you can morph it. This means your triangle contains exactly the same points as the triangle. Here is an advanceed example http://www.carto.net/papers/svg/samples/path_morphing.shtml

Comment: @localghost that path morphing seems great! Any idea how i'd go about doing that with what I have so far?

Answer (score -1):

Here's possibly the simplest way to achieve this effect.  We are actually using a mask rather than a clipPath. We start with a triangle as the mask, then scale up a circle (that is also part of the mask) so that it becomes the same size as the triangle.

This works well as long as the animation is quick.  If you want a slower animation, you would probably want to go with an approach that deforms the triangle instead.

```css
.tri-up
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.tri-up:hover svg .circmask
{
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s;
    transition: transform 0.1s;
}

.tri-up svg .circmask
{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s;
    transition: transform 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<div class='tri-up'>
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200">
        <mask id="clipTriangleUp">
            <polygon points="0,-100, 87,50, -87,50" fill="white"/>
            <circle r="50" fill="white" class="circmask"/>
        </mask>
        <image mask="url(#clipTriangleUp)" 
               x="-100" y="-100" width="100%" height="100%" 
               xlink:href="http://placehold.it/400x400"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: this is great, thanks for responding! I do think I'm looking more for deforming the triangle path to grow or shrink into a circle. I do want the transition to be a bit slower, and this is more of the circle growing over a triangle, rather than a triangle transforming into a circle. That being said, I've been trying to do this for weeks, if no one else responds this might be the option. I can't thank you enough for taking the time to help out!!